# AFNetworking setCompletionBlockWithSuccess asynchronously

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am a new iOS developer, so the question may be very silly, but I can not figure out how to resolve this kind of problem.
Someone could give me some tips.

In the following code, I use the AFNetworking class, and try to print 1,2,3, but I guess `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` has an asynchronous mechanism to make my code print 1,3,2 always.

So how should I do to print 1,2,3?

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation=[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSLog(@"1");


       [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
           NSLog(@"2");

                 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

               NSLog(@"2");

                        }
        ];

[operation start];

NSLog(@"3");
```

Answer (score 1):

`setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:` is an asynchronous method. The block that you pass to the method will be called after the async method is finished.
You may also want to read on block programming: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html